# clear message if reload page

Tags: php, codeigniter

If I reload or refresh page I would like to be able to destroy my message. I only would like the message to show if just come from my site url.

Then say if i press F5 key or mouse to refresh page then message will go away.

How am I able to make that happen. I use user agent to display first message. Still shows message when reload / refresh page.

```
if ($this->agent->is_referral() == site_url('admin/users_group/edit' .'/'. $this->uri->segment(4))) {
$data['success'] = '<i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>  You have successfully modifed users group';
} elseif ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) {
$data['success'] = '';
} else {
$data['success'] = '';
}
```

Comment: you can use unset to unset the message varible like unset($variable) when page loads

Comment: Does not work do you have example?

Comment: Why don't you use Flashdata ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flashdata to do such kind of work.

To set flash Message 
on your controller Use following

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Your Message');
```

and can get this message using

```
$this->session->flashdata('msg');
```

Comment: I know how to use flash data trying not to more session userdata or custom data, for messages problem fixed in my answer in index and edit function.

Answer (score 0):

On the success part of form in controller I set some userdata. I could have done it with flash data but prefer userdata on my index part I added

```
public function edit() {

$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'User Group Name', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_group_id', 'User Group Id', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('permission[modify]', '', 'callback_validate');

if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE) {

$this->getForm();

} else {

$this->load->model('admin/user/model_user_group');

$this->model_user_group->editUserGroup($this->uri->segment(4), $this->input->post());

$data = array(
'success' => 'Congratulations you have successfully added' .' '. "<strong>" . ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $this->router->fetch_class())) .' '. $this->input->post('name') . "</strong>"
);

$this->session->set_userdata($data);

redirect('admin/users_group');

}

}

public function index() {

    $this->load->library('paginations');
    $this->load->model('admin/user/model_user_group');

    $data['title'] = "Users Group";

    $success = $this->session->userdata('success');

    if (isset($success)) {
        $data['success'] = $this->session->userdata('success');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('success');
    } else {
        $data['success'] = '';
    }

    $this->load->view('template/user/users_group_list.tpl', $data);
}
```

On View

```
<?php if ($success) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> <?php echo $success; ?>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: but in this case you need to unset the session. If you use flashdata no need to do anything.